# How to learn multiple binary classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, classification, multilabel-classification

I have an input of shape `14 x 10 x 128 x 128`, where `14` is `batch_size`, `10` is the `sequence_length` and each item in the sequence is of shape `128 x 128`. I want to learn to map this input to output of shape `14 x 10 x 128`, i.e., for each item in the sequence I want to learn 128-binary classifiers.

Does the following model make sense? So, first I reshape my input to `140 x 128 x 128` and then pass it through the model and reshape the output back to `14 x 10 x 128`.

```py
classifier = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv1d(128, 128, 1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.BatchNorm1d(128),
    nn.Conv1d(128, 128, 1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.BatchNorm1d(128),
    nn.Conv1d(128, 1, 1)
)
```

Thank you.

Comment: SO is the opposite of what you ask for - you are required to give *us* a working simple code, and we can help you with an issue you are facing. It is not a place to request code writing.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. I'll update it with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Not really convinced a 1D convolution will get you anywhere since it reasons in two dimensions only. In your case, you are dealing with a sequence of 2D elements. 
Naturally a [`nn.Conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) would seem more appropriate for this kind of task.

You are looking to do a one-to-one mapping with your sequence elements and can therefore consider each one of them as an independent instance. 
Then a straightforward approach is to simply collapse the sequence into the batch axis and use a CNN coupled with a fully-connected layer.

Here is a very minimal example with a single layer:

```
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(1, 8, 2),
                      nn.ReLU(),
                      nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1),
                      nn.Flatten(),
                      nn.LazyLinear(128))
```

This requires you to reshape the tensor before and after to collapse and expand the sequence dimensions:

```
>>> x = torch.rand(14, 10, 128, 128)
>>> y = model(x.view(-1,1,128,128)).view(-1,10,128)
```

Comment: Seems like `LazyLinear` is a new module added in 1.8. What would be the input dimension if I use `nn.Linear` instead?

Comment: Would it be `nn.Linear(8, 128)`?

Comment: And if I were to add another hidden layer, would this be the right way to do it:
`nn.Conv2d(8,8,1)` followed by `ReLU` and `AdaptiveAvgPool2d`?

Comment: (1,2) To determine the `in_features` of your first linear layer, you must know the exact output shape of the preceding later, *i.e.* the adaptive average pool. (3) Only a single `AdaptiveAvgPool2d` is needed because it will reduce your spatial dimensions.